# Is it possible to write code in Xamarin (C#) and then compile it into a library (.a) that I can use in Objective-C?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, .a

Is it possible to write code in Xamarin (C#) and then compile it into a library (.a) that I can use in Objective-C/Swift?

Then, if I could do the same for Java/Adroid, I could write the logic in common C# and the rest of the app in their native environment.

Comment: If I recall correctly (I might be wrong here so wait for someone who is more sure) Xamarin runs on its own vm so I assume the answer is no.

Comment: *what a wonderful world it would be*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The Xamarin bindings only work one-way - Xamarin can consume native code, but native code cannot consume Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be answer op wants, but... there are frameworks that compile C# code into Javascript (that despicable loosely typed) but ubiquitous language that we should all learn well (despite our rejecting it since Netscape 1 because we are strong type bigots).

Alas we see with HTML5 that even MSFT is abandoning their traditional development platforms in favor of (yes, get this, Javascript).  Tough pill to swallow however, we see the open community has done way more in arena of plug-ins to Javascript than MSFT ever did with C#.  C# is powerful, solid, mature, fantastic, but it is not the webbrowser language of choice.

MSFT developed typescript for a reason, we see JQuery which brought name-type addressibility, alas the stage is set for Javascript, Java and C# to either play nice together or get of the "World Stage"  Studying and knowing Javascript, Jquery et. al. is a good thing to do.